# JQuery datepicker - change date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change date format in JQuery datepicker (http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/datepicker/)

Using function dateFormat - http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-ui/1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
        <script id="mobile-datepicker" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#date").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
              });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input data-role="date" type="text">
    </body>
</html>
```

Why it does not work?

Comment: Please define *not work*

Comment: Date format did not change.

Comment: please check my answer @user4362081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Ly0tza3/)

You are missing `id` attribute for your `input`. Since you are initialising your datepicker as `$("#date").datepicker()`, you have to specify an `id` as date to your `input. You are using the [ID Selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) here.

Please take a look at the jQuery selectors in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

**HTML**

```
<input data-role="date" type="text" id="date">
```

**JS**

```
$("#date").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since you are loading your `<script>` in the `<head>`, you will have to use `$( document ).ready()`. Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Ly0tza3/1/). Thus , the updated JS would be as below

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
       dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your block with a document.ready check, otherwise, it will execute before the dom exists and do nothing.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#date").datepicker({
       dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy"
    });
});
```

You also need to add an id on your input:

`<input data-role="date" type="text" id="date">`

Comment: That work but calendar did not display rightly, see image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EhB5U.png

Comment: I would turn that into a new question since your original question is solved.